# Dynamically create columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like the following:

```
   a  b  a1  b1
0  1  6  10  20
1  2  7  11  21
2  3  8  12  22
3  4  9  13  23
4  5  2  14  24
```

where `a1` and `b1` are dynamically created by `a` and `b`. Can we create percentage columns dynamically as well ?
The one thing that is contant is the created columns will have `1` suffixed after the name

Expected output:

```
    a   b   a1  b1  a%  b%
0   0   6   10  20  0   30
1   2   7   11  21  29  33
2   3   8   12  22  38  36
3   4   9   13  23  44  39
4   5   2   14  24  250 8
```

Comment: Can you add your code for `a1, b1` ?

Comment: @jezrael Its a bit complex to put it out here but they are created using pivot from another dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Create new DataFrame by divide both columns and rename columns by [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html), last append to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
cols = ['a','b']
new = [f'{x}1' for x in cols]

df = df.join(df[cols].div(df[new].to_numpy()).mul(100).add_suffix('%'))
print (df)

   a  b  a1  b1         a%         b%
0  1  6  10  20  10.000000  30.000000
1  2  7  11  21  18.181818  33.333333
2  3  8  12  22  25.000000  36.363636
3  4  9  13  23  30.769231  39.130435
4  5  2  14  24  35.714286   8.333333
```

Comment: `(a/a1)*100` will produce 10 for the first value, wouldn't it ? and here it says 6.666

Comment: @YantraLogistics - I understand now, answer was edited.